# How to display cross-tabs of all interactions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a dataset which (in simplified form) looks like this:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"target":[20,30,40], "x1":[1,0,1], "x2":[0,1,1], "x3":[0,0,1]}`

And I want to find the average value of `target` for all possible two-variable `(x_i, x_j)`interactions. So the output should look like this:

[image]

How would I go about doing this in Pandas?

Comment: How working my soluion? Or need something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and for add not exist values [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` created by [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='x1',columns=['x2','x3'], values='target')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels, names=df.columns.names)
df = df.reindex(columns=mux)
print (df)
x2     0         1      
x3     0   1     0     1
x1                      
0    NaN NaN  30.0   NaN
1   20.0 NaN   NaN  40.0
```

If want replace `NaN`s to `0`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='x1',columns=['x2','x3'], values='target', fill_value=0)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels, names=df.columns.names)
df = df.reindex(columns=mux, fill_value=0)
print (df)

x2   0      1    
x3   0  1   0   1
x1               
0    0  0  30   0
1   20  0   0  40
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely works. In the example I posted, I had column names at the top ("x3 and x2"). Is there any way to get that? In my real dataset, I have like 100 variables so it would be helpful to have those.

Comment: @thewhitetie - hmmm, for `100` variables this is theoretically possible by change `['x2','x3']` to `[100 values of list]`, but not sure if readable and what is prformance.